# Best way to track daily file submissions for reporting in SQL

Tags: sql, database

I currently receive daily file submissions from about 100 different locations (recorded in Location table), which are recorded in a FileLog table. I need to determine which locations have not submitted files on which dates, so I can generate a report to send to the location.

At first, I thought this would be simple--just join Location to FileLog and find the Dates with null FileLogIds. That works, but it doesn't tell me what specific days are missing.

I also thought about building a table of calendar dates to somehow join, but I don't know if that's a good idea or not. Does anyone else see a better solution I'm overlooking?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: A calendar table seems like a good idea.

Comment: I second that - it's a good idea